# Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0, Error=MissingBundleIdentifier, did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, xcode7

This is the error in the Simulator log

```
com.apple.dt.Xcode[667] <Error>: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=MissingBundleIdentifier, ErrorDescription=Bundle at path /Users/Monica/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A20C808A-5E72-4B1D-847C-AD6C18B479E9/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a2aXl9/extracted/Potato.app did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist}
```

[image]

This is what my Info.plist looks like:

[image]

This is what my project settings look like:

[image]

I've already done on the Simulator: Simulator > Reset Content & Settings. In Xcode, I've done Product > Clean. I've also tried setting the Bundle Identifier in the Info.plist to the "Monica-Ong.Potato" and "com.Monica-Ong.Potato". I've tried changing the bundle identifier in my project settings to "Monica-Ong.Monica-Ong.Potato". Nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator and rerunning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing this issue, adding CFBundleIdentifier or ProductName or clean / reset ... did not solve my problem.
After digging the problem ( new project from scratch also had the same issue) i found that the assets folder was the blame, i had a referenced folder named Resources and inside i had a folder named Shaders.
I renamed the folder from Resources to assets and it's working now.
I still want to find out what's with the folder naming and why it was giving a totally different error type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Bundle display name` which is "CFBundleIdentifier" in your info.plist to the name of your app. Which is different then the "Bundle identifier" This is used for the pop up messages that says "Potato would like to launch Facebook" and since it is null it crashes. You will also encounter errors if it is set to "".